# Unable to Set VISUAL environement variable in bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to set the `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` environment variables in a server for default usage with crontab.

When I do a manual `export VISUAL=vim`, things work perfectly.

But when I add the lines

```
EDITOR=vim 
VISUAL=vim
```

to my `.bashrc` file and logout and re-login, I don't see any changes on opening `crontab -e`.
If later I do `echo $VISUAL`, I get the response `vim`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Variables set in `.bashrc` are not automatically exported; you still need to use the `export` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put:

```
export EDITOR=vim
export VISUAL=vim
```

in your .bashrc file to make the variables available to the subprocess.

Comment: `to make the variables available to the subprocess` - That is the takeaway here.

Comment: In order to create environment variables (ie variables visible to the subprocesses) you must use export. If you don't use export you are simply creating a global variable, that is usable only in the current shell session.

Answer (score -2):

Works perfectly in my environment ubuntu 12.04.!

Comment: -1 There could be other reasons why it is working in a different environment. Example - one doesn't have nano on his system and editor defaults to vim